# Sieve of Eratosthenes - C language implementation

Tags: c, for-loop, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I am missing something but I can't find what it is. I have also been given a input2.c file and it has a print_prim function which I am not allowed to change.

For n=10 it is always printing

```
4, 5, 7, 9,
```

I know there is an i+2 in **print_prim** function but I can't solve it. Again, I am not allowed to change print_prim function. Can anyone see what am i missing?

---

> main.c

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "input2.h"

int main() {
    int n = lese_int();
    int laenge = n-1; 
    int *array;  
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * laenge);  
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        array[i] = 1;  
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        if(array[i] == 1){
            for(int j = i ; i*j <= n ; j++){
                array[i*j] = 0;
            }   
        } 
    }
    print_prim(array, laenge);
    free(array); 
    return 0;
}
```

> print_prim function

```
void print_prim(int *array, int laenge) {
    for (int i=0; i<laenge; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 1) {
            printf("%d, ", i+2);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: You allocate `malloc(sizeof(int) * (n-1))` but your loop runs while `i <= n`. You write 2 elements  too much.

Comment: Will `i*j <= n` always be smaller than `leange`?

Comment: From the `print_prim` function it is obvious that the entries are shifted by 2. Meaning number 2 is at index 0. `for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {array[i] = 1;}` This must be `array[i-2]` same for all accesses to `array`.

Comment: hi @Holger which loop runs 2 elements too much? a specific one or all of them?

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry no, when I do that, the only output is 2,

Comment: Please, post a question. There is not a question to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a normal sieve shifted by 2 elements.

```
int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n - 1));
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ ) a[i] = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
    if (a[i-2] == 1) {
      for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j+=i ) a[j-2] = 0;
    }
  }

  print_prim(a, n - 1);

  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

- Allocate `n-1` elements to represent numbers from `2` to `n` inclusive.
- Initialize all elements with `1`. Why? Because looking at `print_prim`, it prints values which are equal to 1. So, all our primes need to be shifted by 2 and its value should be `1`.
- Starting with 2, we mark all multiples of prime numbers as `0`. The ones that stay `1` are primes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes for details.
- Since, `print_prim` is shifted by `2`, we need to pass `n-1` as the second argument for inclusive printing.

Comment: Thanks Mukul, It's pretty nice. Can you please explain your approach? I think they are a little bit different.

Comment: Inline fors are hard to expand. If you want to add more lines to that code, you will need curl braces, but a novice programmer doesn't notice it.

Comment: @aomerk, The code shifts by two elements just to ensure the `print_prim` function works as expected.

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos I don't think you are as helpful as you think you are. Please help people other than me.

Comment: @MukulGupta sorry but the part I couldn't understand was, I was looping until j \* i and so on. Your math is little bit different. i \* i , j =i+i and j+= i

Comment: @aomerk The math is the same. Instead of multiplication, I've used addition. In your case you should have done `i*j - 2` as you are using values of `j` from `i`. In fact, we could also start from `i*i` in the inner loop in my case. I'll edit it because it's more optimal.

Answer (score -1):

### Reformatting the code

A common step to help you is to format to us

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "input2.h"

int main ( void )
{
  int n = lese_int();
  int laenge = n - 1; 
  int *array;

  array = malloc( sizeof( int ) * laenge );

  for ( int i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
  {
    array[i] = 1;
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
  {
    if ( array[i] == 1 )
    {
      for ( int j = i; i * j <= n; j++ )
      {
        array[ i * j ] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i < laenge; i++ )
  {
    printf( "%d, ", array[i] );
  }

  printf( "\n" );
  print_prim( array, laenge );
  free( array );
  return ( 0 );
}
```

And the `print_prim` function is:

```
void print_prim ( int *array, int laenge )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < laenge; i++ )
  {
    if ( array[i] == 1 )
    {
      printf( "%d, ", i + 2 );
    }
  }
  printf( "\n" );
}
```

Note: this style is personal and it's not intended to make a religion-like flamming wars using spacing like me, or curl braces down.

---

### Errors found when reading:

You use C99. Take that into account prior to change something. (*know your language*)

You make a memory allocation of `n - 1` elements, but you try to access from the element `2` to the element `n`, both including, in the first `for` loop. (*know how memory allocation works*)

**Arrays start at zero** (*insert joke*), so, you can't reach the element `n` nor the element `n - 1`.

`print_prim` only prints the value plus 2 of the array element that contains 1.
In other words: try to locate all the positions in the array which contains 1, and increment that position with 2. (*know how to read-debugging*)

---

I reccomend you to study how the language works instead of *trial'n'error* based programming. It will save you lot's of hours and you will learn more.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers the question. :/

Comment: There is no question, anyway.